# Linq to Sql: Help with InvalidCastException in my query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have written a SQL query that works just fine, but am having a little trouble with the conversion to LINQ.  Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT        
  CourseID, 
  CourseName, 
  CreditHours, 
  CPTRequired, 
  COTRequired, 
  CPTElective, 
  COTElective
FROM            
  Courses
WHERE        
  (CPTRequired = 'true') 
  AND 
  (CourseID NOT IN
    (SELECT        
      Courses_1.CourseID
    FROM
      Courses AS Courses_1 INNER JOIN
      Sections ON Sections.CourseID = Courses_1.CourseID INNER JOIN
      Enrollment ON Enrollment.SectionID = Sections.SectionID INNER JOIN
      Students ON Students.StudentID = Enrollment.StudentID
    WHERE        
      (Students.StudentID = '11110004')))
```

And here is what I have written so far with LINQ:

```
Dim maj = (From c In connect.Courses _
           Where c.CPTRequired = "True" _
           Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours).Except _
          (From en In connect.Enrollments _
           Join s In connect.Sections On en.SectionID Equals s.SectionID _
           Join cs In connect.Courses On s.CourseID Equals cs.CourseID _
           Join st In connect.Students On en.StudentID Equals st.StudentID _
           Order By cs.CourseName _
           Where st.StudentID = StudentID _
           Select cs.CourseID)
```

When executed the LINQ statement throws the following errors.

> System.InvalidCastException was
>   unhandled   Message="Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery'1[System.String]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1
>   [VB$AnonymousType_6'3[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]'."
>   Source="Final Project"

What am I missing?  I am brand new to LINQ, so please be gentle!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure because the VB syntax has thrown me off, but I believe it is because in the statement prior to the except you are selecting a new anonymous object (with multiple properties) and in the query being passed to Except you are only selecting a single column.  So it is unable to compare the types properly.

Effectively it appears that you are trying to compare:

```
c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours
```

with

```
c.CourseID
```

and LINQ doesn't know how to do that properly..  It may work if you expand the secondary select it include `c.CourseName` and `c.CreditHours`

Making it:

```
Dim maj = (From c In connect.Courses _
           Where c.CPTRequired = "True" _
           Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours).Except _
          (From en In connect.Enrollments _
           Join s In connect.Sections On en.SectionID Equals s.SectionID _
           Join cs In connect.Courses On s.CourseID Equals cs.CourseID _
           Join st In connect.Students On en.StudentID Equals st.StudentID _
           Order By cs.CourseName _
           Where st.StudentID = StudentID _
           Select cs.CourseID, cs.CourseName, cs.CreditHours)
```

But again i'm not all that familiar with the VB syntax so best I can say is give it a shot.

**Edit:**  Moving Context logging code from comment to answer..

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
connect.Log = sw
...Do Query & Enumerate Results...
sb.ToString() 'will contain the generated SQL
```

Comment: You're right about the error, but not the solution... he just cares about duplicate CourseIDs whereas your answer compares that as well as CourseName and CreditHours, which might not work with his data.

Comment: Thanks Quinton.  That did the trick.  Making the select results have the same columns allowed the comparison to work.

Comment: For whatever reason it is ignoring the duplicates in all fields except c.CourseID.  It is giving me the results I am looking for, but I don't understand the reason.

Comment: @Will - I was going to mention that that logic might be different from the actually query presented but it should be enough of a guide to help him understand how the LINQ is being interpreted.

Comment: @stratrider You can attach a TextWriter to your DataContext via `connect.Log = writer` and watch the SQL Output that LINQ is generating to get a better idea of how/why it is working.  I would recommend just making a simple StringWriter/StringBuilder combo or using the Console.Out and check the output in the VS IDE.. if you need some example code let me know.

Comment: I am not familiar with that, so some example code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have the types in your selects be different for Except to work:

Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours
vs

Select cs.CourseID

I think LINQ will compare the whole selected result and compare it.  comparing these unlike results should fail at compile time.  ???

Answer (score 0):

I think the query that you're trying to call Except on hasn't been run yet. Try adding a .toList(), or some other conversion that gives you an IEnumerable, on the end of:

> Dim maj = (From c In connect.Courses _
>              Where c.CPTRequired = "True" _
>              Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours)

Then call Except on the result.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Dim maj = (From c In connect.Courses _
       Where c.CPTRequired = "True" &&_
       !(From en In connect.Enrollments _
       Join s In connect.Sections On en.SectionID Equals s.SectionID _
       Join cs In connect.Courses On s.CourseID Equals cs.CourseID _
       Join st In connect.Students On en.StudentID Equals st.StudentID _
       Order By cs.CourseName _
       Where st.StudentID = StudentID _
       Select cs.CourseID).Contains(c.CourseID) _
       Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours)
```

In other words...

> from x in y where !(from a in b select
>   a.foo).Contains(x.foo) select x